# what is short url concept in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

please discuss what is short url concept in ASP.Net and how to achieve it and also what is the advantage. thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this 'question'?. Do you just want to start a discussion about this subject?

Answer (score 2):

Well the big advantage is that you can easily post short urls to social media where there is a limit of characters allowed, for example twitter.
A second advantage *can be* that the short url is easier to remember.